# Where to find Pycharm matplotlib setting

Tags: pycharm

I'm wondering where to find the pycharm matplotlib setting. Plots in Pycharm Jupyter Notebook automatically add the grid lines as follows, which is very nice.

[image]

Comment: Usually you specify the options you want in the code designating the plot and so not clear on what the question is? In other words, write into your plotting code the style you prefer.